# Is it possible to create a synchronous Gateway

Tags: performance, spring-integration

I'm currently using a spring integration channel through a gateway and see a very strange (and annoying) behaviour. messages are processed extremely late (more than a minute) after they were send.

Since the channel is handled asynchronously by its own thread pool i guess these threads simply aren't active. since sending of these messages is pretty important i would like to force the handling of the message synchronously in the current thread.

is this possible?

My current config:

```
<int:annotation-config />
<task:executor id="integrationPool" pool-size="0-100" />
<int:poller default="true" task-executor="integrationPool" fixed-rate="50" />

<int:channel id="loggableevents">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="outgoingevents">
    <int:queue />
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="loggableevents" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="outgoingevents" method="handleMessage" ref="momadapter" />
<bean id="momadapter" class="my.project.mom.EventSendingMessageHandler" />

<!-- Logging -->
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="loggableevents" ref="loggingadapter" method="handleMessage" />
<bean id="loggingadapter" class="my.project.logging.EventLoggingHandler" />

<int:gateway id="eventgateway" service-interface="my.project.mom.EventGateway" default-request-channel="outgoingevents" />
```

I use the gateway for convenience, would it be better to access the channel directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `<queue/>` element from the `outgoingEvents` channel and it will all run on the calling thread.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html

Answer (score 0):

If you get this answer and are using the interface based gateway. Using the message channel is mandatory. The solution in that case is, use the direct channel. The following code sample shows how to do this using the java DSL.

```
@Bean(name = "spa.import.zipcodes")
public MessageChannel queueRecordsChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
```

Check this page for more information on the DirectChannel:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html